# How to get renamed record types in suite script 1.0/2.0 in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

We can rename record types in Netsuite.

https://system.netsuite.com/app/setup/naming.nl?whence=

I have renamed **Vendor** to **Trader**.
I could get record details by passing **Vendor** as record type to the suitescript 2.0 for below functions

1. record.load
2. record.create
3. search.create

But for **Global search** alone is not working passing record type as **Vendor** and is working for renamed record type 
**Trader**.

1. search.global

Is there any way to get all supported record type details for the user including renamed record type details using suitescript 1/0/2.0?